# How to passing class object Postman

Tags: c#, json, postman

I have an api that needs three parameters, a string(dataType),a class(eloanInput) and a bool(isCluster)

```
public HttpResponseMessage getEloanExcel(string dataType, EloanInput eloanInput, bool isCluster = false) 
{
   var exportDataService = new ExportDataService();
   var exportExcel = new ExportExcel(dataType);
   var inputParams = new CaseSearch.EloanInput();
   inputParams.SEARCH_TYPE = eloanInput.SEARCH_TYPE;
   inputParams.COUNTY_ID = eloanInput.COUNTY_ID;
   inputParams.TOWN_ID = eloanInput.TOWN_ID;
   inputParams.HOUSE_TYPES = (eloanInput.HOUSE_TYPES[0] == "-1" && eloanInput.HOUSE_TYPES.Count() == 1) ? null : eloanInput.HOUSE_TYPES;
   inputParams.HouseProject = (eloanInput.HouseProject[0] == "-1" && eloanInput.HouseProject.Count() == 1) ? null : eloanInput.HouseProject;
   inputParams.PUB_START_DT = eloanInput.PUB_START_DT;
   inputParams.PUB_END_DT = eloanInput.PUB_END_DT;
}
```

just like the image below:

[image: webapi]

I have a problem when testing the API in Postman, I use key, value method to pass my parameters, and only eloanInput gets null, it doesn't get the values I passed to it, but other parameters indeed get the values by the postman.

```
    [Key]         [Value] 

    dataType      'Eloan' 

    eloanInput  { "SEARCH_TYPE": 2,
                "COUNTY_ID": "-1",
               "TOWN_ID": "-1",
               "PUB_START_DT": "2006/11/22",
               "PUB_END_DT": "2006/12/15",
               "HOUSE_TYPES": ["01", "02", "03"],
               "HouseProject": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
               "DONE_START_DT": "88",
               "DONE_END_DT": "108",
               "FLOOR_FROM": "1",
               "FLOOR_TO": "18",
               "BUILD_AREA_FROM": "2",
               "BUILD_AREA_TO": "48",
               "CASE_TYPE": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
               "CASE_CATEGORY": [1, 2, 3, 4],
               "CASENM_KEYWORD": "12"} 

   isCluster    false
```

Postman Request:

[image: postman api testing]

Comment: you need `[FromBody]` attribute and pass that object from body tab *(Visible in PostMan request)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would send that data from the request body (with the help of [FromBody]) and by changing it to `[HttpPost]` method instead of `[HttpGet]`.

Your updated method code:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage getEloanExcel(string dataType, [FromBody] EloanInput eloanInput, bool isCluster = false)
{
   // your code
}
```

and the request from Postman:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! I got the values finally,but for the front-end, how can I pass these three parameters(dataType, eloaninput, isCluster) I am using axios, and the basic format just like this   $axios.post('apiUrl',{   your parameter  })

Comment: @miraclezag Try: `axios.post('/base_url?dataType=abc&isCluster=true', {"SEARCH_TYPE":2,"COUNTY_ID":"-1","TOWN_ID":"-1","PUB_START_DT":"2006/11/22","PUB_END_DT":"2006/12/15","HOUSE_TYPES":["01","02","03"],"HouseProject":[1,2,3,4,5],"DONE_START_DT":"88","DONE_END_DT":"108","FLOOR_FROM":"1","FLOOR_TO":"18","BUILD_AREA_FROM":"2","BUILD_AREA_TO":"48","CASE_TYPE":[1,2,3,4,5],"CASE_CATEGORY":[1,2,3,4],"CASENM_KEYWORD":"12"});`